Request body is Buffer instead of being parsed to JSON in NestJS Fastify
I'm writing a simple API using Nestjs Fastify to test it's feature but the request body is Buffer instead of being parsed to JSON.
main.ts
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { FastifyAdapter, NestFastifyApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter({ logger: true }),
    { rawBody: true }
  );
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
  const port = configService.get('port');
  app.enableCors();
  app.useBodyParser('application/json', { bodyLimit: 10 * 1000 * 1024 });
  // app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  await app.listen(port);
}
bootstrap();

controller
@Post()
async createWallet(@Body() body: CreateWalletDto, @Req() req: RawBodyRequest<FastifyRequest>) {
    console.log('body', body)
    const buffer: Buffer = req.body as Buffer;
    console.log(JSON.parse(buffer.toString()))
    return 'ok';
}

log in console

When I use NestJS Express, the body is already parsed to JSON.
Am I doing something wrong here or is this just the default behavior of NestJS Fastify.
How can I have the request body parsed to JSON before the request reach the validation pipe?

I suspect that Content-Type header is something other than application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded. NestJS has default body parsers for those Content-Types, which is documented here.
So I think you have three options.
If you can change the request:

Change Content-Type header value to application/json in the request

How you do it depends on what method you use to send the request



If you can't change the request:

Manually parse the body (as you have done already)

If Content-Type does not imply JSON


Call useBodyParser for the Content-Type of the request

If the request used specific Content-Type on purpose



